# Fast Levenshtein distance in R?

Tags: r, performance, package, levenshtein-distance, stringdist

Is there a package that contains Levenshtein distance counting function which is implemented as a C or Fortran code? I have many strings to compare and `stringMatch` from `MiscPsycho` is too slow for this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[levenshteinDist](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/RecordLinkage/html/strcmp.html) (from the `RecordLinkage` package) calls compiled C code. Give it a try.

Comment: Just noting the RecordLinkage package is apparently no longer maintained and has been pulled from CRAN. The `stringdist` package is the solution now.

Comment: Just noting the RecordLinkage package is *not* pulled from CRAN, it’s just available: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/

Answer (score 21):

And `stringdist` in the [`stringdist`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf) package does it too, even faster than `levenshteinDist` under certain conditions ([1](http://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2013/09/07/a-bit-of-benchmarking-with-string-distances/))

Comment: stringdist has sped up significantly since that blog you link to: it now uses multiple cores.

Answer (score 6):

You could try `stringDist` from `Biostrings` as well

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `levenshtein_distance()` from the `textTinyR` package. I got 'calloc' memory errors with all other packages when it came to larger character vectors of around 30k characters. Only `textTinyR` worked for me!