# Merge 2 data frames to return all rows of matching measurement names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes like this

```
ID <- c("A","B","C")
Type <- c("PASS","PASS","FAIL")
Measurement <- c("Length","Height","Breadth")
Function <- c("Volume","Area","Circumference")
df1 <- data.frame(ID,Type,Measurement,Function)

ID <- c("A","B","C","C")
Type <- c("PASS","PASS","FAIL","FAIL")
Measurement <- c("Length","Height","Breadth","Breadth_DSPT")
df2 <- data.frame(ID,Type,Measurement)
```

I am trying to merge these 2 data frames in a way that it returns matching measurements and also returns rows that have the matching measurement concatenated by another string.

My **desired output** is

```
  ID Type  Measurement      Function
   A PASS       Length        Volume
   B PASS       Height          Area
   C FAIL      Breadth Circumference
   C FAIL Breadth_DSPT Circumference
```

I use the merge function like this to get the first 3 rows but how do we match the measurement names in the data frames to return all rows that have the match?

```
df <- merge(df1,df2,by=c("ID","Type","Measurement"),all.x=T)
```

Comment: Seems like you're trying to merge data frames based on partial matching? See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617377/merge-data-with-partial-match-in-r

Comment: If I understand it properly, you need to use fuzzy join: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/fuzzyjoin.pdf, since "Breadth" and "Breadth_DSPT" are similar, but not the same

Comment: Is the concatenation always just "string_newpart" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve it is to use the `sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select df1.ID, df1.Type, df2.Measurement, df1.Function
      from df1 left join df2 on (df1.ID = df2.ID and 
                                 df1.Type = df2.Type and 
                                 df2.Measurement like df1.Measurement||'%')")

#   ID Type  Measurement      Function
# 1  A PASS       Length        Volume
# 2  B PASS       Height          Area
# 3  C FAIL      Breadth Circumference
# 4  C FAIL Breadth_DSPT Circumference
```

The last clause in the join (`df2.Measurement like df1.Measurement||'%'`) means that `df2$Measurement` must be equal to `df1$Measurement` followed by any character string, but you can specify a more flexible condition using SQL's `%` and `_`.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply have a concatenation on the end of the string, you can just do something like:

```
merge(
  transform(df2, tmpmeas = sub("_.+$", "", Measurement)),
  df1,
  by.x=c("ID","Type","tmpmeas"), by.y=c("ID","Type","Measurement")
)[-3]
#  ID Type  Measurement      Function
#1  A PASS       Length        Volume
#2  B PASS       Height          Area
#3  C FAIL      Breadth Circumference
#4  C FAIL Breadth_DSPT Circumference
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `data.table` library to do that. First convert your `dataframe` to `datatable`, set the key for each table using `setkey`, then `merge`.

```
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)
setkey(dt1,ID)
setkey(dt2,ID)
merge(dt1,dt2)

#    ID Type.x Measurement.x      Function Type.y Measurement.y
# 1:  A   PASS        Length        Volume   PASS        Length
# 2:  B   PASS        Height          Area   PASS        Height
# 3:  C   FAIL       Breadth Circumference   FAIL       Breadth
# 4:  C   FAIL       Breadth Circumference   FAIL  Breadth_DSPT
```

Comment: Your solution works only for this particular example, not for the general case.