# Find matching string patterns

Tags: r, regex, string

Suppose I have the following data:

```
example = tibble::tibble(
  id = 1:10,
  vac = c("FFizer", "sinovasm", "aztraseneca", "phiser", "sonovac",
          "faizer", "sinivasc", "astraseneca", "sinocav", "aztraxeneca")
)
```

Which looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id vac        
   <int> <chr>      
 1     1 FFizer     
 2     2 sinovasm   
 3     3 aztraseneca
 4     4 phiser     
 5     5 sonovac    
 6     6 faizer     
 7     7 sinivasc   
 8     8 astraseneca
 9     9 sinocav    
10    10 aztraxeneca
```

And I want to find if the variable `lab` matchs in some degree with any option from a vector.

Say the vector to use as identifier is:

```
labs = c("sinovac", "pfizer", "astrazeneca")
```

Crossing `example` data.frame with the vector `labs` should give some output like this:

```
correction = tibble::tibble(
  id = 1:10,
  vac = c("FFizer", "sinovasm", "aztraseneca", "phiser", "sonovac",
          "faizer", "sinivasc", "astraseneca", "sinocav", "aztraxeneca"),
  match = c("pfizer", "sinovac", "astrazeneca", "pfizer", "sinovac",
            "pfizer", "sinovac", "astrazeneca", "sinovac", "astrazeneca")
)
```

Looking like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
      id vac         match      
   <int> <chr>       <chr>      
 1     1 FFizer      pfizer     
 2     2 sinovasm    sinovac    
 3     3 aztraseneca astrazeneca
 4     4 phiser      pfizer     
 5     5 sonovac     sinovac    
 6     6 faizer      pfizer     
 7     7 sinivasc    sinovac    
 8     8 astraseneca astrazeneca
 9     9 sinocav     sinovac    
10    10 aztraxeneca astrazeneca
```

The main idea is to find a way of having a homogeneous `vac` variable

In addition to this, I'd like to create a variable which indicated the "matching degree". I mean, if the string is "FFizer", then its match would be "pfizer" and their matching degree would be around 0.66

Comment: I think you would need to specify a little more about your algorithm. How do you arrive at 0.66? Are you checking how many characters match? What if they are scrambled or different lengths?

Comment: I didn't give any further detail about the "matching degree" because I do not have any clear idea how the matching would be. Actually, I said 0.66 just counting how many characters were common between the two strings. But the main problem is first how to match vac with the lab vector.

Comment: @Cristhian you want to use Levenshtein distance. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182091/fast-levenshtein-distance-in-r) for options + research the algorithm; fits your use-case perfectly in my opinion

Comment: @ctwheels, thank you so much. Reading that post helped me out to find the ```stringdist``` package!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the libraries `fuzzyjoin` and `stringdist`. Using Levenshtein distance:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
library(stringdist)


labs <-  data.frame(vac = c("sinovac", "pfizer", "astrazeneca"))
fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join(df, labs,
                                by = c("vac"),
                                method = "lv") %>% 
  dplyr::rename(vac = vac.x, match = vac.y)
```

**Output**

```
   id         vac       match
1   1      FFizer      pfizer
2   2    sinovasm     sinovac
3   3 aztraseneca astrazeneca
4   4      phiser      pfizer
5   5     sonovac     sinovac
6   6      faizer      pfizer
7   7    sinivasc     sinovac
8   8 astraseneca astrazeneca
9   9     sinocav     sinovac
10 10 aztraxeneca astrazeneca
```

---

The `method` of `fuzzyjoin` takes a [stringdist-method](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringdist/versions/0.9.6.3/topics/stringdist-metrics) from the `stringdist` library.

Additionally, `fuzzyjoin` has the argument `distance_col`, where you can name a column for the computed distance measurement. For example, using Jaro-Winker distance (smaller value is "closer"):

```
fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join(df, labs,
                                 by = c("vac"),
                                 method = "jw",
                                 distance_col = "dist") %>% 
   dplyr::rename(vac = vac.x, match = vac.y)

   id         vac       match       dist
1   1      FFizer     sinovac 0.56349206
2   1      FFizer      pfizer 0.22222222
3   1      FFizer astrazeneca 0.57575758
4   2    sinovasm     sinovac 0.13095238
5   2    sinovasm      pfizer 0.56944444
6   2    sinovasm astrazeneca 0.52272727
7   3 aztraseneca     sinovac 0.51082251
8   3 aztraseneca      pfizer 0.52020202
9   3 aztraseneca astrazeneca 0.03030303
10  4      phiser     sinovac 0.56349206
11  4      phiser      pfizer 0.22222222
12  4      phiser astrazeneca 0.52020202
13  5     sonovac     sinovac 0.15079365
14  5     sonovac      pfizer 1.00000000
15  5     sonovac astrazeneca 0.43290043
16  6      faizer     sinovac 0.56349206
17  6      faizer      pfizer 0.11111111
18  6      faizer astrazeneca 0.44823232
19  7    sinivasc     sinovac 0.13095238
20  7    sinivasc      pfizer 0.56944444
21  7    sinivasc astrazeneca 0.45075758
22  8 astraseneca     sinovac 0.43290043
23  8 astraseneca      pfizer 0.66161616
24  8 astraseneca astrazeneca 0.06060606
25  9     sinocav     sinovac 0.04761905
26  9     sinocav      pfizer 0.56349206
27  9     sinocav astrazeneca 0.51082251
28 10 aztraxeneca     sinovac 0.51082251
29 10 aztraxeneca      pfizer 0.52020202
30 10 aztraxeneca astrazeneca 0.12727273
```

Answer (score 0):

Following some advices here, I read the `stringdist` package and found two useful functions, `amatch` to find a match from a vector according to the maximum distance allowed, and `strindist` to evaluate how different the match is (0 indicates is the same string, and higher value of the distance indicates the string isn't so similar to the target)

```
correction  = example %>% 
  mutate(
    m = amatch(x = vac, table = labs, maxDist = 2),
    matched_to = case_when(
      m == 1 ~ "sinovac",
      m == 2 ~ "pfizer",
      m == 3 ~ "astrazeneca"
    ),
    similarity = stringdist(vac, matched_to)
  )
```

Having this output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
      id vac             m matched_to  similarity
   <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>            <dbl>
 1     1 FFizer          2 pfizer               2
 2     2 astrazeneca     3 astrazeneca          0
 3     3 aztraseneca     3 astrazeneca          2
 4     4 phiser          2 pfizer               2
 5     5 sonovac         1 sinovac              1
 6     6 faizer          2 pfizer               2
 7     7 sinivasc        1 sinovac              2
 8     8 astraseneca     3 astrazeneca          1
 9     9 sinocav         1 sinovac              2
10    10 aztraxeneca     3 astrazeneca          2
```